# cakephp 1.3 favicon

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, favicon

I am  using cake 1.3 and i had tried to implement favicon..But some strang error happens and sometime its showing favicon but for sometimes its not showing it.Pronlem is cakephp img folder path is changing>How can i escape from this problem.

i have used below code in my default.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico','../../app/webroot/img/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon'));?>
```

Favicon shows for following url.

```
http://localhost/finalportal/index.php/events/eventlist
```

Favicon not showing for followin url

```
http://localhost/finalportal/index.php/productsServices
```

I had tried this also.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico',/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon'));?>
```

in this case favicon path is not correct

What i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the first version is that you're using relative paths so it will always end up pointing to the wrong place, depending on how many parameters the URL has. `../../app/webroot` means "two levels down, then to directory app/webroot". Two levels down from `http://localhost/finalportal/index.php/events/eventlist` is `http://localhost/finalportal/index.php/`, but two levels down from `http://localhost/finalportal/index.php/productsServices` is `http://localhost/finalportal/`, so you end up in the wrong place.

The reason why the second method (which is syntactically correct) doesn't work is probably because you have the server set up wrong. Apache's `DocumentRoot` should point at the app/webroot directory **or** the .htaccess file in the root directory should redirect requests to app/webroot.

Comment: seems like its my problem.I am newbee in cakehph even in php.Its like my first project.So can you please write how to rewrite htaccess.I have tried many of the article on .htaccess before.But i could not do any good. Hoping that i can remove index.php from my URL..Its annoying me a lot>>Thax again brother..Looking froward for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

```
meta('favicon.ico',$this->webroot.'img/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon'));
```

It works perfectly, just create favicon.ico image in img folder.thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use relative paths in the `HtmlHelper`, Cake prepends the correct path for you.

I haven't use the meta function, so I'm not sure if it respects the Cake directory conventions (e.g. images are in `img`, JavaScripts in `js`), but this should work:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico','/img/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon'));?>
```

Comment: its not working ..Its showing exactly the samt url we have given in sosource code

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant HTML outputted by `$this->Html->meta()`, so part the `head` section?

Answer (score 1):

use following code to get right path.

```
<?php  echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico',$this->webroot.'img/favicon.ico',array('type' => 'icon')); ?>
```